# Windows 7 Explorer Tree View Does Not Always Expand Current Folder

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

I have the option "Expand to current folder" selected on, but *some* of the folders in my favorites list do not show the directory in the tree view, while others do.

In particular, my documents folder does not expand the tree view, but shortcuts to most folders within it do expand (one such shortcut does not).

The only observable difference is that the ones which don't expand are displayed in the path field at the top of the window as "*username* > My Documents > *path* > *to* > *my* > *folder*" while those that do work display as "Computer > System(C:) > *path* > *to* > *my* > *folder*".  In all cases clicking in the path field changes to a normal folder path from the drive root.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I cannot explain *why* this happens, after much fruitless searching, I discovered by experimentation that if I add a trailing backslash to the path in the shortcut it will work as expected. Which is very strange since the shortcuts which do work do not have a trailing slash.

So, shortcut path:

```
C:\path\to\my\user\folder
```

fails to open up the tree view when clicked, but

```
C:\path\to\my\user\folder\
```

works consistently.

Go figure... and, welcome to Windows, where all the money in the world does not deliver quality software.

Comment: Historically, systems consider `C:\path\to\my\user\folder` as a file, rather that a directory listing. In this case Exporer can't know if the name is a directory or a file beforehand. `C:\path\to\my\user\folder\ ` (due to the last slash) is considered as a proper directory by Explorer. Maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add a trailing backlash to target property, but it was ignored and removed.

My solution: change `My Documents` to `Documents` in the target properties. So,

```
C:\Users\Me\My Documents\Household\Inventory
```

would change to

```
C:\Users\Me\Documents\Household\Inventory
```